# How to improve a router working with namespaces having the same name as a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I am trying to set correctly (and as well as possible) my router.

In the `routes.rb` file I have:

```
namespace :articles do 
  resources :categories 
end

resources :articles
```

In order to work as expected, I *must* state the `namespace` before the `resources :articles` statement so that the router intercepts requests and direct these to the namespace related to articles. Otherwise (if the `resources :articles` is stated before of the `namespace`), as it is possible deduct from the above code, all requests like

```
<my_site>/articles/1
<my_site>/articles/new
<my_site>/articles/1/edit
...
```

are intercepted so that the articles namespace will be "hardly" reached. For example, if you make a request like `<my_site>/articles/categories` it will generate an error as the following:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
Couldn't find Article with ID=categories
```

**So, how can I handle this situation and how can I improve the router code? What do you advice about?**

---

Running the command `rake routes` in my console I get this (as it is ordered):

```
articles_categories GET   /articles/categories(.:format)                                                        
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles/categories"}

POST   /articles/categories(.:format)
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles/categories"}

new_articles_category GET    /articles/categories/new(.:format)                                                   
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles/categories"}

edit_articles_category GET    /articles/categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                              
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles/categories"}

articles_category GET    /articles/categories/:id(.:format)                                                   
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles/categories"}

PUT    /articles/categories/:id(.:format)                                                    
{:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles/categories"}

DELETE /articles/categories/:id(.:format)                                                   
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles/categories"}

articles GET    /articles(.:format)                                                                   
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}

POST   /articles(.:format)                                                                  
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}

new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                                                              
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}

edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                                                         
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}

article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                               
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}

PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                               
{:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}

DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                                                               
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
```

Comment: what does your rake routes say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) about controller namespaces. It says you need to namespace your categories controller like `Articles::CategoriesController` and you need to place your categories controller under `app/controllers/articles` directory.